# Nib file ignoring status bar on load. Why?

Tags: ios, xib, nib

I've got a UIViewController loaded from a NIB at startup. The status bar overlaps the view and there is a status bar sized margin at the bottom of the screen. When the device rotates, the problem corrects itself. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the frame of the controller's view to:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]
```

I've run into this a few times and this is the only real way I know of to fix it. There might be a better way.

Comment: How will this affect rotation?